# How to add objects scaled to the graphics view and screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I am trying to make a PyQt5 application where the user can click on a graphics view window in order to place a rectangle. I managed to scale the window using the fitInView method and that works alright but whenever the windows size is changed the relative size of the newly placed object changes as well. How can I make it so that everything is relative to window/screen/graphicsView size? I tried to use the scene width but it did weird things with scale and position when the window was resized.

Here is my the class for my main window. gv is the graphics view and Ui_MainWindow is from QtDesigner.

```
class Window(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100))
        self.gv.setScene(self.scene)
        self.gv.fitInView(0, 0, 100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        self.gv.fitInView(0, 0, 100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Here is my custom graphics view class:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPolygonF
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, QRectF

class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__(window)

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        rect = self.mapToScene(QMouseEvent.x(), QMouseEvent.y(), 5, 5)
        \\ rect = self.mapToScene(QMouseEvent.x(), QMouseEvent.y(), self.width()/20, self.height()/20)
        self.scene().addPolygon(rect)
```

As a side question am I currently doing this as is recommended? Like using fitInView and mapToScene etc?

Also when I set the scene rectangle what values should I be choosing in place of 100? That was just arbitrary.

EDIT: I managed to achieve something similar to what I want by using the graphics view width as a base variable as shown in the comment in the code above. However I am now having the problem that if you resize the window it shows areas of the scene that were not previously visible. Is there a way to stretch the scene or something like that to make sure it always fills the graphics view?

Comment: The problem could be in the method resizeEvent, you could share the code of the graphic part, ie Ui_MainWindow.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I can but just to check shouldn't that not matter as I reimplemented resizeEvent in the Window class?

Comment: The fitInView function scales all elements, and this causes the rectangles to be re-scaled, from what I understand you use that function to scale the window size, I think you can do that task in a different way.

Comment: I want the things I place to have the same relative size when placed. At present when I make the window smaller and click to place a rectangle then resize the window to normal, that rectangle is much larger than the ones placed when the window is normal. I am okay for the shapes to get smaller as the window size decreases but I want placed shapes to appear at the same size so that no matter what size the window is when I place them all shapes are the same size. If that makes sense?

Comment: Do you want the ratio of the rectangles to the window to be constant?

Comment: I believe so. I tried using the scene width and height but seemed to do weird things with the position as soon as I changed the window size. I may have made a mistake though but unfortunately I cannot check right now

Comment: To understand me better, if the width of the window varies, you want the width of the rectangles to vary in the same proportion, and the same in the height. I am right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so